# Creating a function to remove columns with different names from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have many dataframes that contain the same data, except for a few column differences between them that I want to remove. Here's something similar to what I have:

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(X..x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  X..y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'),
                  var2 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1))
df_list <- list(df1=df1,df2=df2)
```

I am trying to create a function to remove the X, X..x, and X..y columns from each of the dataframes. Here's what I've tried with the given error:

```
remove_col <- function(df){
  df = subset(df, select = -c(X, X..x, X..y))
  return(df)
}
df_list <- lapply(df_list, remove_col)

#  Error in eval(substitute(select), nl, parent.frame()) : 
#  object 'X..x' not found
```

I'm running into problems because not all dataframes contain X, and similarly not all dataframes contain X..x and X..y. How can I update the function so that it can be applied to all dataframes in the list and successfully remove its given columns?

Using R version 3.5.1, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
#Function
remove_col <- function(df,name){
  vec <- which(names(df) %in% name)
  df = df[,-vec]
  return(df)
}
df_list <- lapply(df_list, remove_col,name=c('X', 'X..x', 'X..y'))

$df1
  var1 var2
1    a    1
2    b    1
3    c    0
4    d    0
5    e    1

$df2
  var1 var2
1    f    0
2    g    1
3    h    0
4    i    1
5    j    1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep only the columns with "var"

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) x[grepl("var",colnames(x))])
```

or if you really just want those removed explecitly

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) x[!grepl("^X$|^X\\.\\.x$|^X\\.\\.y$",colnames(x))])
    
$df1
  var1 var2
1    a    1
2    b    1
3    c    0
4    d    0
5    e    1

$df2
  var1 var2
1    f    0
2    g    1
3    h    0
4    i    1
5    j    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking each `list` element for the same column names, it can be automated if we can extract the `intersec`ting column names across the `list`.  Loop over the `list`, get the column names, find the `intersec`ting elements with `Reduce` and use that to subset the columns

```
nm1 <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(df_list, names))
lapply(df_list, `[`, nm1)
#$df1
#  var1 var2
#1    a    1
#2    b    1
#3    c    0
#4    d    0
#5    e    1

#$df2
#  var1 var2
#1    f    0
#2    g    1
#3    h    0
#4    i    1
#5    j    1
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(df_list, names) %>%
     reduce(intersect) %>%
     map(df_list, select, .)
```